# Call Mongoose findOne query once and save result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Inside a NodeJs Express function, data is being retrieved from a Mongoose subarray. The findOne function in Mongoose can only be queried one time. The idea is the data from the findOne query will be saved in an array. I can then paginate the data from the array.

The first time the function is called, the array is populated and page 1 on the webpage displays the results. But when I click next on the html side to load the next page, I get an error.  I tried turning the Mongoose query into an async function but it is not working.

Below is the section of code I'm trying to make work.

```
async function getBookList(param){



   let books = await book_list.findOne({"userId": req.userContext.userinfo.sub},{ 
        newList:{ $elemMatch: {"list_name": param} }});
 
         }


            return books;
       }


    async function GetData() {


     let   tempBookList2 = await getBookList(listName);

      for(i=0; i< tempBookList2.newList[0].books.length; i++) {

       tempArray.push(tempBookList2.newList[0].books[i]);

     }


       }


     if(x == false) {
         GetData().then();
         x = true;
       }
```